# Get window on top without dllimport

Tags: c#, forms, dllimport

Is it possible to check which window is on top without DllImport in C#? Only solution that I found so far, is importing user32 and getting window handle.

Comment: what is the problem with user32 dllimport? one way or the other, windows API has to be used.

Comment: No other way except DllImport

Comment: I'm just wondering is there alternative solution, one thing that comes to my mind is get all window handles of my process, and for each form check isActive().

Comment: That way you can only check for the Forms that you are managing. What if your internet browser comes on top? you will still get isActive as true for your Form but it is not on the top.

Comment: You'd like to find out which of your own window is on top? Is your program using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Windows Forms, i want to know if any of forms of my process is on top

Comment: "On top" is hopelessly ambiguous.  You check if your app owns the *foreground* window with the Form.ActiveForm property.  It is *null* when it doesn't.

Comment: Problem with user32 dllimport is, if i run application under linux that won't work.

Comment: then you should look for mono specific calls that you can use.